# Add border and text inside own button class

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem. I want to add text below the Icon and I want to add a border with a background. How can I do that?

I don't know how can I add a text inside the border with a background. What is the best option?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

import '../utils/definitions.dart';
import 'icons.dart';
import '../model/label.dart';

class LabelButton extends IconButton {
  final Label? label;

  //counter feedback!

  LabelButton(
      {required this.label, required VoidStringCallback? process, Key? key})
      : super(
            key: key,
            icon: Icon(iconList
                .firstWhere((element) => element.name == label!.uiIcon)
                .icon),
            iconSize: 80,
            onPressed: () {
              process!(label!.name);
              HapticFeedback.lightImpact();
            });
  const LabelButton._(this.label, {Key? key})
      : super(key: key, icon: const Icon(null), onPressed: null);
  static LabelButton createBlank() {
    return const LabelButton._(null);
  }
}
```

What I tried:

I tried to change this with an ElevatedButton that I can use a background and label.

```dart
class LabelButton extends ElevatedButton {
  final Label? label;

  //counter feedback!

  LabelButton(
      {required this.label, required VoidStringCallback? process, Key? key})
      : super(
            key: key,
            icon: Icon(iconList
                .firstWhere((element) => element.name == label!.uiIcon)
                .icon),
            iconSize: 80,
            label: Text('Test'),
            child: ,
            onPressed: () {
              process!(label!.name);
              HapticFeedback.lightImpact();
            });

  const LabelButton._(this.label, {Key? key})
      : super(key: key, icon: const Icon(null), onPressed: null);

  static LabelButton createBlank() {
    return const LabelButton._(null);
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share an image of the sample output?

Comment: To add a text below the icon and a border with a background to your button, you can use the ElevatedButton widget and combine it with other widgets to achieve the desired layout.

Answer (score 1):

Try out below code

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
          side: BorderSide(width: 2.0, color: Colors.black),
        ),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        primary: Colors.blue, // Change the background color as needed
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        process!(label!.name);
        HapticFeedback.lightImpact();
      },
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Icon(
            iconList
                .firstWhere((element) => element.name == label!.uiIcon)
                .icon,
            size: 80,
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 8.0),
          Text(
            'Your Text Here',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom button and customise it.

```
  class CustomButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback? onPress;
  final String? title;
  final Color borderColor;

  const CustomButton({
    Key? key,
    this.onPress,
    this.title,
    this.borderColor = Colors.blue,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: onPress,
      child: Container(
        height: 40,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: const DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage('assets/bg.png'), fit: BoxFit.fill),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
          border: Border.all(color: borderColor),
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            title!,
            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If you want an icon with the text, then replace the **Text** with **Row** or **Column** and add an **Icon** widget.

Below is an example:

```
Row(
          children: [
            const Icon(Icons.radio_button_checked),
            Text(title!),
          ],
        )
```

Use it like this wherever you need it.

```
CustomButton(
    onPress: (){},
    title: "Button Title",
    borderColor: Colors.green
)
```

Don't forget to import the class like this.

```
import '../../res/shared_widgets/custom_button.dart';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:workspace/base/extension/context_extension.dart';

class BorderIconContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  Color? borderColor;
  String text;
  Color? textColor;
  Color? bgColor;
  Color? iconColor;
  double dynamicHeight;
  double dynamicWidth;
  double? iconSize;
  IconData icon;
  VoidCallback onTap;

  BorderIconContainer({
    super.key,
    this.iconColor,
    required this.onTap,
    required this.icon,
    this.textColor,
    this.iconSize,
    required this.dynamicHeight,
    required this.dynamicWidth,
    this.borderColor,
    required this.text,
    this.bgColor,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {},
      child: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * dynamicHeight,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * dynamicWidth,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(
            width: 2.0,
            color: borderColor!,
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          color: bgColor,
        ),
        padding: context.paddingNormal,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Icon(
              icon,
              size: iconSize,
              color: iconColor,
            ),
            SizedBox(height: context.dynamicHeight(0.02)),
            Text(
              text,
              style: context.textTheme.bodyMedium?.copyWith(color: textColor),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}



  BorderIconContainer(
                iconColor: Colors.black,
                icon: Icons.camera,
                textColor: Colors.black,
                iconSize: 48.0,
                dynamicHeight: 0.2,
                dynamicWidth: 0.2,
                borderColor: Colors.black,
                text: "Camera",
                bgColor: Colors.grey,
              ),
```

You can try this code block and output is below

[image: example]